# Dynamic form field using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to gather the input data from a form dynamically rather than typing out each individual input field name.  This was pretty easy using standard React, but I'm switching over to React Hooks and now I'm a bit confused on how to achieve the same goal.

```
const gatherFormData = e => {
  if (e.target.value !== null) {
    _.assign(
      formData.payload,
      { [e.target.name]: e.target.value, action },
      { groupNumber },
    );
    setState({ 
      [e.target.name]: (e.target.value),
      formData
    });
  }
};
```

I tried using template literal syntax, but that didn't work.

```
set`${e.target.name}`(e.target.value);
```

Comment: there is template literal syntax in hooks? maybe try and post a minimal example of your class and ask how to convert it to hooks.

Comment: @DennisVash are you referring to the Standard React portion of my question?

Comment: When do you say Standard React do you mean react classes? I've never heard that expression before, using react hooks is a standard too.

Comment: My bad, yes, React classes.

Comment: So like I mentioned above, post a minimal example of your class and ask how to convert it to hooks. Your question is unclear, what does "achieve the same goal."

Comment: In my above snippet, I'm dynamically gathering the form data as the user types so that I don't have to write a state variable per form field.  I'm trying to perform the same objective using React hooks instead.  Obviously my template literal solution was a fail, but unclear on achieving the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useState` with an object, making it so you can dynamically add stuff. Example:

```
const [targets, setTargets] = useState({});
// Set values like this
setTargets({...targets, [`${e.target.name}`]: e.target.value});

// Then get values:
const theValue = targets.yourTargetNameHere
```

When setting the value, you have to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`{...targets`) in order to maintain the other values you put in the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3><a href="https://cluemediator.com">Clue Mediator</a></h3>
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="box">
            <input
              name="firstName"
              value={x.firstName}
            />
            <input
              className="ml10"
              name="lastName"
              value={x.lastName}
            />
            <div className="btn-box">
              {inputList.length !== 1 && <button className="mr10">Remove</button>}
              {inputList.length - 1 === i && <button>Add</button>}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{JSON.stringify(inputList)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So, how are you going to handle onChange?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to to add new input fields dynamically using a button and track those input fields with state. This is how I solved this problem.

```
  const [newMembers, setNewMembers] = useState(['']);
   const addAnotherMember = () => {
setNewMembers(state => [...state, '']);
};
const handleChange = (e: any, i: any) => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    setNewMembers(state => [...state.slice(0, i), email, ...state.slice(i + 1)]);
  };
  const handleRemove = (index: any) =>
    setNewMembers(state => [...state.slice(0, index), ...state.slice(index + 1)]);
enter code here
return ( <div>
 {newMembers.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <div className="relative ">
                <FormInput
                  label="Email address"
                  type="text"
                  value={newMembers[i]}
                  setValue={setValue}
                  onChange={(e: any) => {
                    handleChange(e, i);
                    enableButton();
                  }}
                />

                {i > 0 ? (
                  <span
                    className="absolute subdomain__mask cursor-pointer"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleRemove(i);
                    }}
                  >
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      className="h-20 w-20"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"
                        strokeWidth="2"
                        d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                ) : null}
 </div>);
```